# How to make TCP socket connection work over WAN with different ISP?

Tags: networking, tcpclient

I recently made a very basic TCP server application in C++ and Python using the very basic socket API. The client server connection happens flawlessly within the localhost as well as inside my LAN (within the same Wi-fi). But If I connect my client to an internet service (WAN) and try to connect to my server application behind my wifi (using the Wi-fi's public IP (provided by its ISP) and the port on which my server will be listening to) , I'm unable to get a connection. The server sits idle waiting for a connection ! I have enabled port forwarding on my Wi-fi, but still the results are all vain...

**EDIT: **
 I managed to connect them over WAN, but now the ISP have to be the same... This is what I did: I made the server run on my Android device, bound it to the IP of my device that uses mobile data... The client sits behind a WiFi and connects to the Server using the previously mentioned IP and everything works fine ! But however if the client becomes an android app in another device with mobile data provided by different ISP everything fails !!! * So long as client runs behind a WiFi, but server connected to WAN (same ISP) the system works. *

Comment: Vivekanand, thanks for trying to spread the questions to sites where you think they are relevant. However, this is clearly not a programming question, and I've asked for migration to super user. Please read the help pages of the relevant sites to know what is on topic and what is not. This clearly doesn't contain a programming question (usually, if it doesn't contain a language / runtime tag then the question is off topic here, as indicator. It will also not gain much attention if such a flag is missing...).

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Thankyou very much, for your consideration !